Set tracing log level from commandline in libtest_mimic
I have a Rust project with tests that use libtest_mimic to run tests written in cucumber. Throughout the tests the tracing-crate is used for logging. Ideally I'd like to set the log level through the commandline, but libtest_mimic has its own Arguments-struct that that is parsing the commandline-arguments with let args: Arguments = Arguments::from_args();.
The problem is that Arguments::from_args() doesn't allow any commandline-args that are not inside Arguments. If I add anything in the commandline after the test-specification (like --loglevel WARN) I get an error, that this isn't recognized (as it is not in the Arguments-struct. So I would have to modify the commandline-args somehow to remove the --lovlevel WARN-part before they are processed by libtest_mimic.
This seems rather wrong and ugly and I thought maybe there is a better way that I missed somehow.
Does anyone have an idea of how I can use tracing inside libtest_mimic-tests?

What logger is used? If it's env_logger then you could set $RUST_LOG.

ah sorry it's "tracing" ( https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/ )


The problem is that Arguments::from_args() doesn't allow any commandline-args that are not inside Arguments.

Arguments implements clap::Args, so you can embed it in another clap arguments struct:
#[derive(clap::Parser)]
struct MyArguments {
    #[command(flatten)]
    test_args: libtest_mimic::Arguments,
    
    #[arg(long)]
    log_level: Option<String>,
}

